# selecting different columns each row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe which has 500K rows and 7 columns for days and include start and end day.

I search a value(like equal 0) in range(startDay, endDay)

Such as, for id_1, startDay=1, and endDay=7, so, I should seek a value D1 to D7 columns.

For id_2, startDay=4, and endDay=7, so, I should seek a value D4 to D7 columns.
However, I couldn't seek different column range successfully.

Above-mentioned,

1. if startDay > endDay, I should see "-999"
2. else, I need to find first zero (consider the day range) and such as for id_3's, first zero in D2 column(day 2). And starDay of id_3 is 1. And I want to see, 2-1=1 (D2 - StartDay)
3. if I cannot find 0, I want to see "8"

Here is my data;

```
data = {
        'D1':[0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1],
        'D2':[2,0,0,1,2,2,1,2,0,4],
        'D3':[0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0],
        'D4':[3,3,3,1,3,2,3,0,3,3],
        'D5':[0,0,3,3,4,0,4,2,3,1],
        'D6':[2,1,1,0,3,2,1,2,2,1],
        'D7':[2,3,0,0,3,1,3,2,1,3],
        'startDay':[1,4,1,1,3,3,2,2,5,2],
        'endDay':[7,7,6,7,7,7,2,1,7,6]
        }
data_idx = ['id_1','id_2','id_3','id_4','id_5',
            'id_6','id_7','id_8','id_9','id_10']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=data_idx)
```

What I want to see;

```
df_need = pd.DataFrame([0,1,1,0,8,2,8,-999,8,1], index=data_idx)
```

Comment: Could you explain why `id_1` has the value 1 in `df_need`?

Comment: id_1 startDay=1 and endDay=7. So, we should look, D1 to D7 columns. In D1=0. It’s our first 0. D1=1st column and startDay=1. So, 1-1=0

Comment: startday = 4. So please check your expected output

Comment: If id_1’s startDay= 4, we should look D4 to D7(endDay=7)                And first 0 is D5 (range=D4 toD5). So, 5-4=1(output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create boolean array to check in each row which 'Dx' column(s) are above 'startDay' and below 'endDay' and the value is equal to 0. For the first two conditions, you can use [`np.ufunc.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html#numpy.ufunc.outer) with the `ufunc` being [`np.less_equal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.less_equal.html) and [`np.greater_equal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.greater_equal.html#numpy.greater_equal) such as:
import numpy as np

```
arr_bool = ( np.less_equal.outer(df.startDay, range(1,8)) # which columns Dx is above startDay
            & np.greater_equal.outer(df.endDay, range(1,8)) # which columns Dx is under endDay
            & (df.filter(regex='D[0-9]').values == 0)) #which value of the columns Dx are 0
```

Then you can use [np.argmax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) to find the first `True` per row. By adding 1 and removing 'startDay', you get the values you are looking for. Then you need to look for the other conditions with [np.select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to replace values by -999 if `df.startDay >= df.endDay` or 8 if no `True` in the row of `arr_bool` such as:

```
df_need = pd.DataFrame( (np.argmax(arr_bool , axis=1) + 1  - df.startDay).values, 
                        index=data_idx, columns=['need'])
df_need.need= np.select( condlist = [df.startDay >= df.endDay, ~arr_bool.any(axis=1)],
                         choicelist = [ -999, 8], 
                         default = df_need.need)

print (df_need)
         need
id_1        0
id_2        1
id_3        1
id_4        0
id_5        8
id_6        2
id_7     -999
id_8     -999
id_9        8
id_10       1
```

One note: to get -999 for `id_7`, I used the condition `df.startDay >= df.endDay` in `np.select` and not `df.startDay > df.endDay` like in your question, but you can cahnge to strict comparison, you get 8 instead of -999 in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much!
One more question;
If I need calculate average between startDay and endDay, how can I calculate.
Ps: no ".values == 0" condition. Just need average of D_startDay to D_endDay for each rows.

Comment: @patronlargibi first remove the last condition `& (df.filter(regex='D[0-9]').values == 0)` from `arr_bool` and then do `df.filter(regex='D[0-9]').mask(~arr_bool).mean(axis=1)`, you should get the mean per row for all values between start and end. You may also add `.fillna(-999)` at the end of the previous command to spot where your startDay is bigger than endDay :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply(:.
so new arr_bool and df_need should be; 
```new_arr_bool = ( np.less_equal.outer(df.startDay, range(1,8)) 
            & np.greater_equal.outer(df.endDay, range(1,8)) 
            )
```
and ```new_df_need = pd.DataFrame( df.filter(regex='D[0-9]').mask(~arr_bool).mean(axis=1), 
                        index=data_idx, columns=['need'])```
Am i wrong?

Comment: @patronlargibi as you renamed the boolean mask like `new_arr_bool`, you should use this one in mask such as `...mask(~new_arr_bool)...`